# Are there resolution enhancement filters in image processing?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Well I would like to know are there resolution filters in MATLAB that preserves the image characteristics?

Comment: isn't the question legitimate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize it. It will become a little bit blurry. So then you sharpen it:

```
I2=imresize(I,2);
I2=conv2(I2,fspecial('unsharp'));
```

Here is an example:

1) The original image:

[image]

2) The resized image:

[image]

3) The sharpened resized image:

[image]